# Only show block if View or nid has certain term referenced to it

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have a tricky one here and looking for some suggestions.

I have a Page view which uses a contextual filter on the nid (which is in the URL).

These nodes have a term reference field which contain various terms.

I have a block which I only want to be displayed on this page if the node has this specific term referenced to it. Bare-in-mind this is not the actual node page, this a dynamically created page/view based on the nid in the url.

Comment: Are you using drupal 7?

Comment: yes Drupal 7 mate

Answer (score 1):

Did you try php code? If you enable '[PHP filter](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/php/)' module, you can add php code under 'Pages restricted to certain pages' option in block configuration and write your code like

```
<?php
$relative_path = request_uri();
if (some condition)   {

    return TRUE;
   }


 else
    return FALSE;

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try below steps,

1. Crearte a hook for the block display alter,
   hook_block_view_MODULE_DELTA_alter()    // To alter specific block
2. Inside the hook, render the view using below code,
   $my_view = views_get_view($my_view_name); // To get related Taxonomy term for the node
3. Check if the Taxonomy term exists.
4. Manage display/hide for the block.